# autofill doesn't work inside iframe in safari

Tags: reactjs, iframe, safari, autofill

It's impossible to set a value from autofill options on form inside iframe

Project main technologies - react - 18.2.0, react-frame-component - 4.1.3
Browser and OS - Safari 16.6 on Ventura 13.5

We use iframes without the src attribute to embed forms on other websites. It's impossible to set a value from autofill options but if src attr is set it will be applied(pasting a form directly from an url)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried to change restrictions with a sandbox attribute(allowed all of them)
I tried to allow the shared-autofill option(as far as i understand it works in Chrome only)
Changed autocomplete values for inputs - from 'on' value to 'tel, email, given-name, family-name' foe example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.